# Red Screen Error from Debug Build appear in Release Build

Tags: react-native

I'm building a release build of my application through using `./gradlew assembleRelease`. When fetch an api, if network request fail occur a alert message would only appear saying `Connection error....etc` in release build of previous app. While in debug build, a red screen error and the alert message would appear. Now in the release build, the red screen error would also show.

```
export function GetUserDetail(){
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem('loginState')
      .then((result) => {
        if (result!==null){
          var json=JSON.parse(result);
         fetch(////domainurl/////, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization' : json.token,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              "params": {
              }
            })
          }).then(e => e.json())
          .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(getuserdetail(response.result));
          }).catch((error) => {
            ToastAndroid.show('Connection Error, Please check if you have internet connnection', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            console.error(error,"ERRRRRORRR");
          });
        }
        else{

        }
      })
    }
}
```

Expected : release build - alert message appear

Actual : release build - alert message & red screen error appear

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, apparently public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() return true instead of return BuildConfig.Debug.